# What are the sources of data on Data.gov?

Tags: usa, data.gov

I was browsing through the datasets on the website, and datasets like "[Tax Year 2007--](https://explore.data.gov/Population/Tax-Year-2007-County-Income-Data/wvps-imhx)" caught my attention. At first I thought it might be [Census](http://www.census.gov/#) data. However, if you look at the "About" tag for that dataset it says it's from the IRS. I also noticed that you can filter by agency through the menu on the left of [this](https://explore.data.gov/catalog/raw?limitTo=datasets&utf8=%E2%9C%93) page I was using to browse the datasets. It would be nice to have some sort of grid view for just the contributing agencies that provided stats about their contributions.

**Is this a comprehensive list of contributing agencies, and is there a way to view all of them at once other than the small list view?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of all organizations that are contributing data (or metadata) to Data.gov can be found in two different places.

One place is on the [Federal Agency Participation](https://www.data.gov/metrics) link at the bottom of the page.  Clicking on an agency or sub-agency name takes you to a page with all of the raw datasets and tools submitted by that agency.

There is also [a listing of all organizations](http://catalog.data.gov/organization) (which includes non-Federal entities) at the top of the Catalog page, and shows a description of the organization as well as the listing of all datasets and resources from that organization on Data.gov.

(Disclaimer: I am the Evangelist for Data.gov.)

Comment: +1 that is exactly what I was looking for. I think I even brushed over that page but didn't realize it was what I wanted. Note about Disclaimer: If I could +2 I would, I'm glad there are already experts in this community!

Comment: Glad I could be of help! I think I'm learning more than sharing in this new community.

Comment: Another thing to note about the new CKAN-based model for Data.gov is that there will be a great, restful API of the entire catalog and its metadata, so you could mash that up pretty easily.  A similar example can be found from HHS - http://healthdata.gov/data/dataset/healthdatagov-catalog-api.

Comment: A recent upvote for my answer brought me back to this thread. My link has changed, but redirects. Jeanne's link (at the end of paragraph 2) is 404. This seems to be the current correct link: https://inventory.data.gov/dataset/f6f06df8-c102-4fe8-af31-c368be66166d/resource/d65072b5-08f0-4f90-bd57-65e731c59df2

Comment: Thanks @JoeGermuska for the note. I've updated the answer to reflect the new locations on the redesigned page.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds exactly like what you are looking for:

["This dataset provides distribution of all datasets provided by all Departments/ Agencies/ Organizations in Data.gov"](https://explore.data.gov/dataset/Data-gov-Federal-Agency-Participation/aubg-mfc9)

Answer (score 1):

Jeanne probably has some other ways to get to it, but you can get a list of the possible agencies by going to the [raw data catalog](https://explore.data.gov/catalog/raw), and on the left side there's an option to limit by agency.  You can click 'view all' to get the full list.

Unfortunately, I suspect that it's a list of all agencies, *not* those that have actually contributed.  And you then have to repeat it with the geodata catalog to get a full count.